# How to make primary key from 2 Foreign keys in MySql EFCore

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-code-first-mapping

i have some issue with making primary key from 2 foregin keys

model examples: Element, Color, ElementToColor

ElementToColor should contain 2 foregin keys that representing the Element and Color relation

```
[Key,Column(Order = 1)]
public Int ElementId {get; set;} 

[Key,Column(Order = 2)]
public Int ColorId {get; set;}
```

but when i tring to add the migration it's faild

> ElementToColor must have primary key

but it's wrong to make primary key for that king of mapping table, it will make dublicate data

1,1,1

2,1,1

...

what should i do in that case

**I use:**

application: asp.net core 2.1 webApi

database: MySql

ORM: MySql EFCore

Answer (score 0):

found it, i needed to use fluent API:

in the ApplicationDbContext i should override method OnModelCreating like that:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ElementToColor>().HasKey(e => new { e.ElementId, e.ColorId }
    );
```